# Copied working app, but "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(…)"

Tags: angularjs

I am afraid that I can't post code, as there is too much of, but am hoping that someone will recognize my problem.

I have an existing, working app, which I want to use as the basis for a new one.

So, I copied all of `localhost/<some directory>/App1` to `localhost/<some directory>/App2`, but when I try to load the app, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined(…)`

I just don't understand it. I have copied the entire directory and changed nothing. The first app still works fine, but the copy gives that error.

Any idea what I am doing wrongly?

Comment: what's the url of you app?

Comment: Probably you are loading the paths from directory 1 check the network tab

Comment: 1) the URL is stated in the question. 2) sorry, but I don't understand your point. App1 had no internal reference to URL/directories

Comment: URLs of the scripts that you are loading in the app

Comment: OIC. All are relative paths, and the entire directory tree was copied, so they are all existing

Comment: What are the errors you are seeing in the console?